# Regarding Dynamic resource pool configuration

Tags: hadoop-yarn

"Dynamic resource pool configuration" of yarn queue is present in Cloudera Enterprise.

Does "Dynamic resource pool configuration" option is also present in HDP 3.1.0? Is there any way to enable it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's just marketting and "Dynamic Resource Pools" are actually just [yarn que's](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html) by a different name. (And they're is [tooling in Ambari](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.5.0/using-ambari-views/content/amb_using_yarn_queue_manager_view.html) to manage them.)